# MIgrate sql 2008 to 2014 with sp 2010

Tags: 2010, sql-server-2012

I have a customer with SP 2010 Foundation and Sql Srver 2008, now they want to migrate only the DB Server to SQL 2014, I am looking for detailed explanation so I can give an estimate, but cant find anything like this.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 does not support SQL 2014. They can use SQL 2012. Here is the process to move all databases for a farm:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725(v=office.14).aspx